# How to test RxJs observable callback with NgRx setState

Tags: testing, jestjs, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to know how to test the code inside a `.subscribe` callback, with the subscription being on a NgRx store selector.

Environment: Angular 13, RxJs 7+, NgRx 13, Jest 27

Consider

**my-component.ts**

```
...
ngOnInit {
  this.myValue = true;
  this.store.select(mySelector).pipe(filter(data => data.attribute === true)).subscribe(data => {
    this.myValue = false; // I want to test this
  }
}
...
```

**my-component.spec.ts**

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let store: MockStore;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({
          initialState: { myFeature: { } },
        }),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  });

  it('should perform animation & redirect to /dashboard if login successful', () => {
    store.setState({
      myFeature: {
        ...
        attribute: true,
      },
    });

    expect(component.myValue).toBe(false);
  });
```

This works, but it's random. Since this is asynchronous I could test myValue before the subscribe callback has been called and the test would fail, for example if my subscribe callback takes time to do stuff, like so (I'm adding a delay of 500ms) :

```
...
ngOnInit {
  this.myValue = true;
  this.store.select(mySelector).pipe(filter(data => data.attribute === true), delay(500)).subscribe(data => {
    this.myValue = false; // I want to test this
  }
}
...
```

This fails.

How can I wait the callback to perform before testing my value ? I could wait an arbitrary time like 1 sec before testing, but it could break at any time in the future it's not robust enough. Like :

```
it('should perform animation & redirect to /dashboard if login successful', 
async () => {
    store.setState({
      myFeature: {
        ...
        attribute: true,
      },
    });
    await lastValueFrom(timer(600)); //rxjs 7
    expect(component.myValue).toBe(false);
  });
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `waitForAsync` and `fixture.whenStable` to ensure completion of async tasks before evaluating the `expect`.

```
it('should perform animation & redirect to /dashboard if login successful', waitForAsync(() => {
    store.setState({
      myFeature: {
        ...
        attribute: true,
      },
    });
    
    fixture.whenStable()
      .then(() => expect(component.myValue).toBe(false));
  }));
```

Comment: It's not working :(
I think it simulates the passage of time, but here this is "real" time, the time for the callback to execute.

Comment: It should ‘fast forward’ and complete all async operations regardless. A stack blitz would be useful, they are tricky to incorporate testing into but it’s possible. Thinking about it more it is likely because the subscribe in your component is ‘detached’ via ngrx so fakeAsync doesn’t know about it. I have another idea I’ll post later.

Comment: Changed the answer, I have tested this with the `delay` and it works.